# Выделение имени.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Мы проверяем домашнее задание друга Саши()Димы.

Ставится ли здесь знак,и какой?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы поставила тире, Дима - приложение к сочетанию "друга Саши", стоит в конце предложения.  Мы проверяем задание друга Саши (какого?) - Димы.

Comment: Хотела попробовать расставить знаки препинания именно в этом предложении, но не получается. Нет у него ни интонации, ни нормальной структуры.

Answer (score 2):

Хорошо бы это предложение переделать, а то его в таком виде никакой знак препинания не украсит. Например, напишем так:
(1) Мы проверяем домашнее задание Сашиного друга Димы. - Знаков препинания нет, приложение в нормальной позиции перед определяемым словом. Это если вы поясняете, кем является Дима.
(2) Мы проверяем домашнее задание Сашиного друга, Димы. - Ставится запятая, уточняющее приложение. Это в том случае, если у Саши много друзей, а сейчас речь идет конкретно о Диме.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что в данном предложении "Дима" является именно уточнением, и должен быть выделен запятой.